# Web App Layout --- Show / Hide Div Elements Based on Web App View

Tags: javascript

I am trying to layout a web app. Each screen of my web app is a panel. I have the following panels right now: home, about, settings, game, and results. I only want to display one panel at a time. Right now only the home panel should show but my code is not working (all panels are showing right now). What am I missing?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bNzVA/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
window.onload = myOnloadFunc;

function myOnloadFunc() {
    var homePanel = document.getElementById("homePanel");
    var aboutPanel = document.getElementById("aboutPanel");
    var settingsPanel = document.getElementById("settingsPanel");
    var gamePanel = document.getElementById("gamePanel");
    var resultsPanel = document.getElementById("resultsPanel");

    // All panels in app
    var panels = ["homePanel", "aboutPanel", "settingsPanel", "gamePanel", "resultsPanel"];

    // Show selected panel and hide all other panels
    function showPanel(panel) {
        for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            if (panel) {
                // Show panel
                this.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                // Hide
                this.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    showPanel("homePanel");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- homePanel -->
<div class="panel" id="homePanel">
Home panel
</div>

<!-- aboutPanel -->
<div class="panel" id="aboutPanel">
About panel
</div>
</body>

<!-- settingsPanel -->
<div class="panel" id="settingsPanel">
Settings panel
</div>

<!-- gamePanel -->
<div class="panel" id="gamePanel">
Game panel
</div>

<!-- resultsPanel -->
<div class="panel" id="resultsPanel">
Results panel
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you closing the <body> tag so early?

Comment: That's a typo, editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of issues in the code.

1. `this` keyword. The way you used it referred to the global object, i.e. Window.
2. iterated over panels but not assign it to anything.
3. store nodes in `panels`
4. compare panels nodes to the node you pass into showPanel

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bNzVA/2/

```
// All panels in app
var panels = [homePanel, aboutPanel, settingsPanel, gamePanel, resultsPanel];

// Show selected panel and hide all other panels
function showPanel(panel) {
    for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
        var p = panels[i]
        if (p === panel) {
            // Show panel
            // this referred to global object, i.e. window
            p.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            // Hide
            p.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

showPanel(homePanel);
```